# Usage of Grep Command to match a pattern

Tags: grep

How do i use grep command to filter the ip address.

```
3267  3        77.80.177.0/24       00:00:00:00:00:00 100011    0     0     0    0 y
3289  1        177.77.1.0/24        00:00:00:00:00:00 100010    0     0     0    0 y
```

I want to filter only the entries starting with 177. which appears on column 3.
There is no uniform spacing between columns.

sorry I'm not comfortable using grep . I tried to google and got some examples but did not work the way that I intend do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 grep " 177\."   File
```

That should do it

Comment: It works in this case but does not have any check to the `3rd column` condition.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier with `awk`:

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /^177/' file
3289  1        177.77.1.0/24        00:00:00:00:00:00 100010    0     0     0    0 y
```

`'$3 ~ /^177/'` means: in case the 3rd field contains an string that starts with 177, then print it.

To have it done with `grep`:

```
$ grep -E "^\w+\s+\w+\s+177" file
3289  1        177.77.1.0/24        00:00:00:00:00:00 100010    0     0     0    0 y
```

`-E "^\w+\s+\w+\s+177" file` means: look for strings with this pattern: start of line, word, spaces, word, spaces, 177.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `awk` over this but here are both solution:

With `grep`:

```
grep -vE '\s*177\.([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]\/[0-9]+\s*' inputFile
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '$3!~/^177/' inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, here's another one:

```
$ grep -o '[^.0-9]177.*/[0-9]{2}'
```

Results in (note the leading space):

> 177.77.1.0/24